# how to consume SOAP Pass-through service from Azure API management in c#

Tags: c#, azure, api, soap, api-gateway

i have hosted WCF service in Azure API management as SOAP Pass-through. Trying to consume this API from client which already has request to WCF service. How i can get soap request template

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Any code?

Comment: @rkrathna could you tell me what is " soap request template". Is that you want to get the api definition file form Azure API management?

Comment: @Jim i'm trying to consume my legacy WCF services as SOAP Pass-through in my client application with same implementation had for WCF services. I mentioned soap envelope request as soap request template